# Why not use nvarchar(max) also for small fields instead of nvarchar(123)

Tags: sql-server

Why not use `nvarchar(max)` also for small fields instead of `nvarchar(123)`.

Let us assume we do have not any values larger than 4000 Bytes.

Are there any difference in Terms of Performance when we have a `nvarchar(max)` also for smaller fields. Or why do People use then `nvachar(SOME_FIX_VALUE)`?

Comment: Consider you are a doorman, do you want to open the door for more people than allowed?

Comment: Getting a free sanity check that someone's not adding the complete works of Shakespeare into a column that should just contain e.g. a name seems like nothing but a bonus.

Comment: This is a good example. I want the doorman to decide this (actually some ASP.net code which evaluates a form). In my case the value gets truncated and it causes an exception. I want to avoid this exception and instead go trough a verfy process before inserting it into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important reason is indexing. 
Indexes can only be as large as 900 bytes. So with max you would never be able to put an index on the column.
This will cause issues with performance for many.

Another reason is to keep data consistency. A lot of databases communicate one way or the other with other systems and of course users. It might be via webservices, applications or similar.
And there a fixed length might be a business rule that field "region" can only be X letters long. This means if you use max you'll never have any inbuilt control regarding your data integrity and have to build additional security layers.
So while you add validation to the UI, what happens if an import causes issues, a manual scripting error etc.

Other reasons are that the data base engine handles variable text. For example data pages in SQL Server are 8KB pages. So it has to assume things when you start using variable text. For example check out: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
But now we start becoming very technical and then you're properly better to take this to the database version of Stackoverflow.

The main reason for a coder/user is the index in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are difference. First, the `varchar(max)` columns could end up stored out of row, as a LOB. Second, you can fool the optimizer in thinking that there's lot more data than actually is, and in some cases produce suboptimal query plans.

Answer (score -1):

If a table with varchar(max) columns went to 1,000,000 rows then that's a huge table and most of the disk space is wasted.

Comment: Except that `(n)varchar` columns only use as much space in each row as is required for the data in that row (plus 4 bytes to store the length).